# panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter with multiple requests to the same Endpoint

Tags: go, goroutine

Im doing a hashed password generator, i have an endpoint at the server that generates a goroutine to create the hashed password, and then send it as a response when the goroutine ends.

this is the function that is called to generate the hashed password

```
func SetHash(c echo.Context) error {
    hashedhPassword := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go utils.GenerateSaltedHashAsync("demoprueba", wg, hashedhPassword)
    return response.Success(c, map[string]string{
        "salt": <-hashedhPassword,
    })
}
```

and this is the hashing class

```
package utils

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/argon2"
    "sync"
    "tigoApi/config"
)

const (
    Time         = 4
    Memory       = 64 * 1024
    KeyLen       = 80
    Threads      = 10
)

var environment = config.Instance()

func GenerateSaltedHashAsync(password string,wg sync.WaitGroup, hashedPassword chan string) {
    cryptoKey := argon2.IDKey([]byte(password), []byte(environment.SaltedPassword), Time, Memory, uint8(Threads), KeyLen)
    encodedPassword := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(cryptoKey)
    consoleHash := fmt.Sprintf("%s$%d$%d$%d$%d$%s$%s", environment.PepperPassword, Time, Memory, Threads, KeyLen, environment.SaltedPassword, encodedPassword)
    defer wg.Done()
    hashedPassword <- consoleHash
    wg.Wait()
}
```

everything works fine when i do a single request, however when i send multiple requests at once(stress test) the app send this error.

> panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter
>
> goroutine 1566 [running]: sync.(*WaitGroup).Add(0xc0001320a0,
>   0xffffffffffffffff)
>           /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:74 +0x139 sync.(*WaitGroup).Done(0xc0001320a0)
>           /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:99 +0x34 tigoApi/utils.GenerateSaltedHashAsync(0x8e5324, 0xa, 0x0, 0x2,
>   0xc000226240)
>           /home/crdzbird/goApps/src/tigoApi/utils/hashing.go:46 +0x3cc created by tigoApi/controller.SetHash
>           /home/crdzbird/goApps/src/tigoApi/controller/user_controller.go:23
>   +0xcd
>
> Process finished with exit code 2

please anyone can tell me what is wrong with the code.

UPDATE.

Thanks to the suggestions the code working should be like this...

```
func SetHash(c echo.Context) error {
    hashedhPassword := make(chan string)
    go utils.GenerateSaltedHashAsync("lacb2208", hashedhPassword)
    return response.Success(c, map[string]string{
        "salt": <-hashedhPassword,
    })
}


func GenerateSaltedHashAsync(password string, hashedPassword chan string) {
    cryptoKey := argon2.IDKey([]byte(password), []byte(environment.SaltedPassword), Time, Memory, uint8(Threads), KeyLen)
    encodedPassword := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(cryptoKey)
    consoleHash := fmt.Sprintf("%s$%d$%d$%d$%d$%s$%s", environment.PepperPassword, Time, Memory, Threads, KeyLen, environment.SaltedPassword, encodedPassword)
    hashedPassword <- consoleHash
    close(hashedPassword)
}
```

Comment: Never copy `sync` structs - if something needs a reference use a pointer.

Comment: Also why `wg.Add(2)` is there another waitgroup task not listed in the question? If there's only one task in your `waitgroup` then change this to 1.

Comment: im gonna changed it, but why is needed to be changed from 2 to 1?

Comment: Because you're only starting one goroutine (more accurately, because there's only one call to `wg.Done`). Also there's no call to `wg.Wait()` anywhere, which makes the whole `WaitGroup` pointless - it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why the negative votes? the question isn't offtopic as far i can know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `sync` package [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/):

> Values containing the types defined in this (sync) package should not
>   be copied.

So if something needs a reference use a pointer.

Change your function signature so `wg` is a pointer reference:

```
func GenerateSaltedHashAsync(password string,wg *sync.WaitGroup, hashedPassword chan string)
```

and then call with that reference:

```
go utils.GenerateSaltedHashAsync("demoprueba", &wg, hashedhPassword)
```

Comment: That was the issue!! thanks for your help! :) im gonna mark the answer as solved when the 5 minutes has passed

Comment: Note that this fixes the panic but the WG still doesn't do anything because there is no call to `Wait()`.

Comment: I updated the code, i forget to add the wg.Wait() inside the function utils.GenerateSaltedHashAsync()

Comment: @LuisCardozaBird If you only have one sub-task to wait on - a `sync.WaitGroup` may be overkill. And since you're using a channel to write the pending result back - I think all you need is a channel/close to coordinate this asynchronous task.

Comment: mmm... yeah actually i was viewing that the group maybe a little overkill as you was saying, im gonna remove the group, thanks for the the suggestion, im new in the implementation of channels and goroutines. im gonna update the code again :) @colminator